# CDC Tables and Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Can local CDC tables be replicated to AzureSql Data Base using Transactional Replication?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And I'm not looking for "add the CDC table to replication", but rather, what business problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried ,but seems like ,its not possible..

If you try to add a CDC table as an article to a publication you will receive an error, as they are marked as ms_shipped:

> Msg 20696, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addmergearticle, Line 251
>   The object [cdc].[SalesLT_Customer_CT] is marked as shipped by Microsoft (ms_shipped). It cannot be added as an article for merge replication.

References:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/615f2ed1-2d93-49dd-8dc9-0440ad7ffd6d/replicating-cdc-change-tables?forum=sqlreplication